# FitNesse running remote test cases locally?

Tags: fitnesse

The background is : I am trying to implement an automated integration test solution.  I want to have a FitNesse server running which QA/Users can maintain the test cases.  During our nightly build, we want to have the test run locally in the build machine.  (In our build script, we are going to startup Jetty, and FitNesse test cases are invoking the RESTful APIs)

When I am looking into the fitnesse-maven-plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/fitnesse-maven-plugin/), in the description of goal fitnesse:run, it said that:

> This goal uses the fitnesse.runner.TestRunner class for calling a remote FitNesse web page and executes the tests or suites locally into a forked JVM

However, when I am using this plugin with FitNesse version 2009xxxx or 2008xxxx (with a special patch of this maven plugin), I found that the test is not running locally.  Instead, I saw new test results created in the remote FitNesse wiki server.

May I know if it is due to change of behavior of FitNesse? (Coz the fitnesse maven plugin is depending on a much older version of FitNesse)  Also, with the original Test Runner being deprecated, is it possible to have the behavior I am looking for? (Pages defined in remote server, but run locally in build machine)

Or, is such way of work no-longer a recommended approach to use FitNesse? (If so, I will need to change the approach of the automated test)

Comment: Just to add one more info: in the test, I am using RestFixture to connect to localhost.  It is fine if I am having the FitNesse server running on local machine, but not in another machine (connection refused). All these make me believe that the tests are not run locally.

Comment: Another thing to add: I created a fixture which will write to a local file.  After running the test cases, the files are generated in the remote machine but not the local machine.  That seems quite sure that the tests are not run locally  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I've used is the wiki import option feature. This can import the latest changes from the remote wiki to your local build server.

http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WikiImport

You can also tell it to auto-update when running the tests rather than having to re-import manually whenever they change.

Another possibility is to use a source control plugin to automatically commit changes by QA/Users from the remote wiki and pull them down as part of your build.

Comment: Though I run into another problem when I am using WikiImport (Trinidad plugin halt after running the tests), but at least this approach seems work fine.